# Concatenating varying number of lines notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a file where i need to take varying number of lines and concatenate into one. It could be two, three, or four lines that require concatenation. There is a common set of characters (say 'xxx') that begin the first line of each set of lines i want to concatenate. Is there a means in notepad++ to look for 'xxx' and concatenate every following line until the next 'xxx' is detected?

I should add i also have a value 'yyy' at the end of the each 'last line' that might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that real examples are always the best examples ;)

I don't know whether it's possible to modify the match before replacing in notepad++, but if the number of line to concatenate is limited to four, you could just run these four search & replace operations:

search: `^(xxx.*)\n(.*yyy)$`
replace: `\1\2`

search: `^(xxx.*)\n(.*)\n(.*yyy)$`
replace: `\1\2\3`

search: `^(xxx.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*yyy)$`
replace: `\1\2\3\4`

and so on.

if anybody needs this for a high number of lines, please comment and I'll do some research on this.